# Trouble creating Object Data Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, objectdatasource

I'm using VisualStudio 2012. I wanna create a demonstration project to be deployed in IIS.

This project must have an aspx page with a ReportViewer which will show a local processing report. By local report, I mean it won't use Reporting Service, the project's compiled code must build its own report.

I'm using the tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251784.aspx

But when I create a report from Report Wizard, "Choose a Data Source Type page" isn't shown. I'm presented to the "Choose Your Data Connection page", where I should set a connection to a DBMS.

I don't wanna create the report from a DBMS, I want an Object Data Source. It will be a List  of Plain Old C# Classes, that will be fed to the report. I don't want the report viewer to access the DBMS directly.

BusinessObjects.cs was properly created and it's in the root of the project.

I F6 compiled the solution, cleaned it, closed VS and reopened. It simply doesn't let me create a data source that's not from a DBMS.

Is there anything the tutorial ommited and I'm missing?

Comment: I also tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xf878ky%28v=vs.110%29.aspx but there's no Data Menu.

Comment: I also searched for "Add new data source" in the Quick Launch search, nothing was found. I think I must install something...

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0a9a50a4-9d1d-4422-93d2-d3fc9f1dd435/where-did-the-data-menu-go-in-vs-2012?forum=vssetup also has the issue. View->Other Windows->Data Sources is not available.

Comment: Shift + Alt + D opens DEBUG submenu, no Data Source either!

Comment: I created some different project types. For example, File > New > Web Site > ASP.NET Reports Web Site. Still only bad luck.

Comment: I created a project of type "WCF Service Library". For tha project, the Project menu has a Add New Data Source item!! It opens the infamous Choose a Data Source Type dialog!! I created a POCC and was able to create a datasource for it. Then I created a report, and in Choose the Dataset dialog I was able to select the data source I created, and POCC's properties were available!! Now, how can I create a Web Project to do the same??

Comment: You appear to be trying to create an asp.net web project that includes a report viewer control, in which case you are looking at the wrong tutorial - the one you have linked to is for *Windows Forms* development. Try this one instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251692.aspx

Comment: That tutorial seems to be the same. In my VS2012, if I go File > New > WebSite, there's no "ASP.NET Web Site" template, and in Report Wizard's Data source field there's no global option. The solution seems to be choose a proper project template, where I can go Project > Add New Data Source. From the Choose a Data Source Type dialog I can choose Object Data Source and can create a report from it. The problem is that the only template where I can use Add New Data Source is WCF Service Library, which doesn't aim web apps.

Comment: If you don't see "ASP.NET Web Site" listed as a templte then it sounds like you don't have a full version of Visual Studio installed, are you sure you are not using an Express version, or the version installed with SQL Server (BIDS / SQL Server Data Tools)?

Comment: It is VS 2012 Ultimate, it should have all features. I'm gonna ask the installer and see if some module isn't installed. What should I look for in it?

Comment: And if I can create Object Data Source in a WCF Service Library, why can't I create in other templates? I have many (7) templates available for a WebSite project. Why only 1 allows Object Data Source and only that one isn't available for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

I created a new project with a "ASP.NET Empty Web Application" template. Inside the solution I created another project with a "ASP.NET Server Control" template.

I used the serve control project as application layer, and the empty webapp project as presentation/UI layer.

In application project I created the Object Data Source and added that project to UI project's reference. With that I was able to create an asp page in UI project that consumes the application object data source.

GG